# sencha cmd5 phonegap does't create .apk file

Tags: android, cordova, touch

I am using Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231 and phonegap 3.5.0-0.21.14 to make an sample integrated sencha touch-2.4.0 and phonegap Android project.
1. I do first step like this:

```
sencha -sdk /var/www/touch-2.4.0 generate app mp mp
```

Initiate process works true and a touch project will be initiate correctly.
this resault will shows:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /home/funfullson/test/mp/build/temp/production/mp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.json
```

1. I entered the mp and run this command:

   sencha phonegap init com.test.mp mp

this step is done truely. the result is this:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[INF] Creating App
[INF] Adding native build to app.json
[INF] Application has been initialized for native packaging. Please edit app.json and add platform(s) to build for.
```

Now there is no file name phonegap.local.properties in mp directory.
And when I tried to make a native apk with the below command:

```
sencha app build native
```

faced to some WARN and as mentioned below and at the end no apk file is created:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : native
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /home/funfullson/test/mp/build/temp/production/mp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/bootstrap.json
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.Decorator.setDisabled) -- /home/funfullson/test/mp/touch/src/Decorator.js:158
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.data.ArrayStore.loadData) -- /home/funfullson/test/mp/touch/src/data/ArrayStore.js:65
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (me.callParent in Ext.dataview.DataView.onAfterRender) -- /home/funfullson/test/mp/touch/src/dataview/DataView.js:893
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.fx.animation.Wipe.getData) -- /home/funfullson/test/mp/touch/src/fx/animation/Wipe.js:120:7
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.slider.Toggle.setValue) -- /home/funfullson/test/mp/touch/src/slider/Toggle.js:64
[INF] Concatenating output to file /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/app.js
[INF] merging resources into /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/resources
[INF] merging resources into /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/resources
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css 
[INF] Copying page resources to /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www
[INF] Writing content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/index.html
[INF] Writing content to /home/funfullson/test/mp/phonegap/www/index.html
[INF] [Phonegap] Attempting PhoneGap local build for android
```

Comment: I have also this problem. Some people are waiting reply since August to the same issue on another forum.